# Windows XP guest in VMWare Player 3 cannot maximise player windows

Tags: vmware, windows-xp

Setup: Ubuntu 10.04 64bit with dual monitor setup (1 dvi and 1 vga)

I have a scenario where I am running a Windows XP guest in vmware player 3. If I try and maximize the vmware player window it maximizes and starts jumping between both monitors every few seconds. I end up having to drag the player window bigger manually to fill a monitor.

How can I fix this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try switching to VirtualBox. I have no experience in VMWare, but I'm sure VirtualBox OSE is just as good, if not better.